# Auto insert a dropDownList when a new row

Tags: excel, excel-2007, ms-office, vba

I have an excel sheet with three columns. (Name), (Surname) and (Identity Type). The colum identity type  can take only 3 values, (Id,Passport,Drivers Licence). What i want is when the user Start writing on new row then a dropdownlist with those 3 values on the column Identity Type should be appeared. Is that possible?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: this is not a code question; Stack Overflow is code related

Comment: it could be a vba question

Comment: @whytheq: This can be achieved with (worksheet_change) or without code :)

Comment: @whytheq: Yup you are right

Comment: @user1292656: You can achieve it without code or with code. Please tell us your preference. If it is without using code as :@whytheq showed below then I will have to flag this question so that it can be moved to the relevant forum.

Comment: I prefer with code because the number of rows are not predefined. So i do not want to fill all the rows with this dropdown. I want it to be created when for example the user starts typing in a new row

Comment: Ok Record a macro and do as @whytheq showed below. Next amend that code and use that in the worksheet change event. In the code make the code run when the user types in the relevant cell by trapping typing in that cell. Give it a try and if you are stuck then post the code that you tried and we will take it from there.

Comment: Use a `named range` for your validation - then it doesn't matter if rows get inserted

Comment: "So i do not want to fill all the rows with this dropdown"....you just highlight all the rows and then apply validation _once_; no need to select each cell one at a time !!

Comment: The point is that I am going to send this template to my customers to fill the rows. So I do not want to tell them to do this procedure every time

Comment: Every customer will input different amount of rows. Thats why the dropdownlist should be appear automatically on each row

Answer (score 1):

Not really any need for VBA use [**Data Validation**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Dqo9I6yP3Nc):

Highlight all the cells in the column which you'd like to add this drop-down into.

The in the `Data` menu you need to choose `Data Validation`. You should then get the following and you need to select the three values which you want in the drop-down:

[image]

This results in:

[image]

Or am I misunderstanding your question ?

Comment: The point is that the dropdowlist should be appeared in each new row and not just once

Comment: Have you tried data validation before? The above will appear in all the yellow cells - on all the rows!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but instead of selecting a cell for the validation, select the entire column.  This will add the validation to all cells in the column and will give you the drop down on all rows as your data expands.